# Synchronize DbContext with changes in Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently developing a multi user data management system in .NET 4.0.

My frontend is a WPF application which retrieves all the data from a SqlExpress Server. I am using the latest Entityframework version as main datalayer to read and write to the database.

The software has to handle following scenario. Each Frontend (WPF Application) can add and modify data in the database which is created by the client hisself. The client is not allowed to modify / delete records from other users therefore each Entity has stored the username information on the main entity.

Here you can see the datamodel I am using (EF Code First Approach).

[image]

I am using this Query to load all the data into the frontend application:

```
public static Context GetDataContext()
{
    return new Context(Settings.ServerConnection);
}

public Project LoadProject(int id)
{
    Remoting.Context = GetDataContext();
    Project = Remoting.Context.dbsProjects.Where(p => p.Id == id)
.Include(p => p.Categories.Select(x => x.Templates.Select(y=>y.Properties.Select(xx=>xx.Binding))))                                                
.Include(p => p.Categories.Select(x => x.Templates.Select(y => y.Links)))
.Include(p => p.DataSources).FirstOrDefault();

            OnPropertyChanged("Project");
            return Project;
        }
```

After that initial load all data is displayed correctly in my frontend. So far so good that was the easy part.

Now I want to synchronize my DbContext, which is a long living context, lives for the complete runtime of the MainWindow. Means when another frontend inserts updates data which belongs to him, I want to display it also in all the other clients.

I have found a solution how to refresh all already existing entities within one context, therefore I use this lines of code:

```
var refreshableObjects = Remoting.Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Select(c => c.Entity).ToList();
    Remoting.Context.ObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, refreshableObjects);
```

I am not sure if this is the right solution, but so far it works for me.

So far i can refresh all already loaded entities, but i have no idea how i can detect entities which are created or deleted by another frontend which is running at the same time. Is there any build in mechanism to refresh the initial linq query that loads or removes entities which are new in the database?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd try Remoting.Context.Entry(Project).Reload(); and see if it gets child objects too.

Comment: @C.M.unfortiunatly this does not work, it only refreshes all existing entities but does not load new ones or remove old ones.

Comment: Why do you need long living context?
In general i would try to create contextPerRequest, if  it's impossible, you can turn off change tracker by `Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` or `AsNoTracking`.

Comment: @zxxc, i think i need a long living context as the data is displayed in multiple windows (avalondock) and the user also has the possibility to manipulate this data. How should i track changes if i do not have a long living context?

Comment: Why don't use a service WCF to provide data and changes ?

Comment: @Shim-Sao, its a local client system (wpf Application) without any server technology.

Comment: And what is the problem ? Windows is based on services, no need server for that. Documentation here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf . From doc : A service endpoint can be part of a continuously available service hosted by IIS, or it can be a service hosted in an application. It's what I am doing a combo WPF + WCF with all my SQLite datas provided by the service.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but services are made for that.

Comment: @Shim-Sao you are right i could implement a self hosted wcf service pretty easy but i am actually looking for a method without a service as i do not see a real need for it. From my point of view it does not make a big difference, if a service detects the changes or each client detects them. It's a "small" data application with up to 5 clients maximum which would be polling for changes.

Comment: Ok I see. Maybe Concurrent Namespace can be the trick : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @shim-sao i think the concurrency is not the problem, as a user can only delete / modify data which is created by himself. Right now I am just looking for the right way of loading / synchronizing data using my dbcontext. zxxz wrote that it's a bad idea to use a long living dbcontext to detect changes. I read multiple articles in the web of using dbcontext in a standalone application and the main message i got from them was to use one dbcontext per window instead of using short lived dbcontext per call.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue years ago by using `Service Broker`. I have done a little research about this issue about how this is solved nowadays and it seems that it is done the same way. Searching on GitHub I found the following project that should suit your needs:
[monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency)

Using this library you can listen on the `SqlTableDependency.Change`-event and get notified when entries on a table are updated, inserted, deleted.strong text

Comment: This one looks really promising. I have 2 questions regarding this solution. Right now the Change Event triggers every time when something is inserted/deleted/updated, is there any possiblity to find out which client the update did, means when one client makes a change the client itself also gets the notification but this one does not need to update as he was the updating client. The second thing is i could not make it work using sql windows authentication, is there any limitation on this?

Comment: @ManuelBleimuth for Question 1: just query the data and throw the result away if the data is from the current client. There should not be any performance issue if you query `X` or `X-1` times. Question 2: does it work with any other authentication method? please be ware of the permissions you need. Please see the readme on the GitHub repository.